# Google Cloud Vision API Testing

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine), to start working on Google Cloud Vision platform. I tried the following steps:

1) Created the project

2) Created the bucket

3) I also ran the following code:

4) Ran each code given in the tutorial line-by-line

When I'm running this part of the code, it's throwing the following error.

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
--job-dir=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/data \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--region us-central1 \
--config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
-- \
--train_dir=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/data \
--pipeline_config_path=${BUCKET_NAME}/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
```

Error:

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz'
>
> If you would like to report this issue, please run the following
>   command:   gcloud feedback
>
> To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
>   gcloud info --run-diagnostics

I'm configuring the pipeline as following:

```
sed -i "s|gcloudstuff/visionex/models|"${BUCKET_NAME}"/data|g" object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
```

Comment: try to look into your TF setup - as the errors says no 'slim' directory, which you must have set during installation. check if you have the dir slim/dist/ ?

Comment: did you run the TF object detection API installation test - python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py ?

Comment: @NabeelAhmed: Thanks for your comment! I was following the tutorial almost exactly it's mentioned. Since there was no test mentioned I didn't try any test. Could you specify how to do the test. Since I downloaded the "model" folder, it has the slim directory. In the model execution code 2 packages are required "object detection" and "slim". I can't able to find how to do this part.

Comment: I copied the statement from in the installing the TensorFlow Object Detection API section. Verify if you have the slim/ added in PYTHONPATH - execute the command - python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)" - and share look in it